# Adding a new parameter to constructor on the base class means I have to refactor all of the classes that inherit from it?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am using Castle Windsor Inversion of Control Container.

I have found that if I need to inject a new component via the constructor on the base class, then all child classes inheriting from it need to pass that component to the base's constructor. This is expected.

But what if I have dozens of children inheriting from that base class, and dozens of unit tests instantiating those child classes. Do I really need to go through and refactor all those constructors and calls to those constructors? Am I missing a design pattern that would allow me to easily modify a base class constructor without having to then refactor all the children of that class?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] so we can see a concrete example. But, _generally_ speaking, yes. You will need to refactor those unit tests.

Comment: `Am I missing a design pattern that would allow me to easily modify a base class constructor without having to then refactor all the children of that class?` Add a new constructor but leave the old one there also.

Comment: Base classes with dependencies are often an indication of a design issue; many consider them a smell, which is why the "composition over inheritance" mantra exists. Base classes are strongly coupled to their sub types, which is why you'll often see cascading changes to their sub types, which is what you are seeing now with your constructor dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a direct solution to your problem would be packing up the dependencies of the base class to a new class like `BaseDependencies` on which the base class depends on, in this case, you just need to add a new member to `BaseDependencies` if there is a new dependency for the base class.
The code would be something like this:

```
class Base {
public Base(BaseDependencies d) {}
}

class BaseDependencies {
public DependencyA {get; set;}
public DependencyB {get; set;}
public DependencyC {get; set;}
}
```

The other option might be refactoring your code to reuse logic by class composition instead of inheritance.
see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You are going to have to mock the dependency out and pass it into the constructor when unit testing your classes.

I assume that all the children inheriting the base class use that dependency, so why would you expect not having to pass this in?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing a design pattern [...]?

Yes, use interfaces instead of base classes. Interfaces don't have constructors, so you'll never run into that sort of problem with interfaces.

[Anything you can do with a base class, you can also do with composition](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/02/26/inheritance-composition-isomorphism).