# Adding parameter to base class constructor, auto-add to all descendants

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor, automation, containers

I am trying to improve some code to take out initialisations and use of the Service Locator in my View Model, so that the container can create them within the constructor. But there are changes to base classes that have hundreds of descendants and this will take a long time to manually fix everyone.

Is there a way that Visual Studio or any other add-in can do this for you? On the descendant it will need to add it into the main constructor and pass it through to the base constructor also. There is only a single constructor on all.

e.g. I have just added the someNewInjectedClass parameter to the base class constructor below:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private ISomeNewInjectedClass _someNewInjectedClass;

    public BaseClass(ISomeNewInjectedClass someNewInjectedClass)
    {
        _someNewInjectedClass = someNewInjectedClass;
    }
}
```

And that needs to be added to my descendant which is currently this:

```
public class OneOfManyDecendants : BaseClass
{
    public OneOfManyDecendants() 
        : base()
    {

    }
}
```

To become this:

```
public class OneOfManyDecendants : BaseClass
{
    public OneOfManyDecendants(ISomeNewInjectedClass someNewInjectedClass) 
        : base(someNewInjectedClass)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the fix you want to do? It's not clear from your question

Comment: Congratulations, you just learned why inheritance hell is awful.

Comment: Just updated with example. Ha indeed @asaf92!

Comment: I know that Resharper has some options to modify parameters in functions that try to change the existing function calls, but your specific case is a bit different. If it's really too much to do manually than honestly I'd resort to using a singleton (which is another code-smell) instead of changing everything everywhere

Comment: However, in the future I suggest that in your designs you avoid inheritance and instead use composition and interface implementation in order to prevent code duplication and achieve polymorphism. Inheritance doesn't scale well and IMO should be avoided

Comment: Ignoring all unrelated [inheritance rant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57273536/1997232), not every change has an easy to use refactoring option. So hundereds of manual changes might have to happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Resharper you can use "Change Signature" (Ctrl+R,S) refactoring. When doing it select "Resolve with call tree" option. In a next dialog pick "Create parameter..." option for each subclass.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that he needs to change the deriving classes constructor signatures as well, I'm not sure Change Signature covers it (I could be wrong which would be a pleasant surprise)

Comment: It covers, I've updated my answer with screenshots.

Comment: Oh my god I had no idea! Resharper is so awesome sometimes :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, it's good to know there is a quicker way to do this. I may use this in combination with the other answer I presented below.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to my exact question but I am going to go a long the lines of @sinatr's suggestion with this related post: [Use class as a single parameter for base parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288927/440675)

This seems the best way for us going forward and can more easily change in the future.